# Webpack 5.74.0 Dev Server Compiling but Not Serving Files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I recently updated my WebPack version to 5 and now I am having trouble serving the files for development.

When I run it I see this:

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.2.160:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/PATH/public/' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished
asset bundle.js 1.98 MiB [emitted] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 2 related assets
orphan modules 16.2 MiB [orphan] 2469 modules
runtime modules 27.8 KiB 15 modules
cacheable modules 5.38 MiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.83 MiB 419 modules
  asset modules 32.8 KiB
    data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width=%27.. 2.39 KiB [built] [code generated]
    data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%27.. 342 bytes [built] [code generated]
    + 29 modules
  modules by path ./src/ 3.52 MiB 15 modules
  optional modules 30 bytes [optional]
    crypto (ignored) 15 bytes [optional] [built] [code generated]
    crypto (ignored) 15 bytes [optional] [built] [code generated]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.
Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  bundle.js (1.98 MiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (1.98 MiB)
      bundle.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

webpack 5.74.0 compiled with 4 warnings in 22225 ms
```

And the files don't load with: `GEThttp://localhost:8080/assets/bundle/bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]`
And interestingly the /webpack-dev-server endpoint shows bundle.js at that link but when I click it from there it also 404s

Config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets/bundle/'),
        publicPath: "assets/bundle/",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.mjs', '.gql']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        static: {
          directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
        },
    }
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "NAME",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "dev-server": "webpack serve"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/URL.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/URL/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/URL",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/api": "^4.0.54",
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^4.6.7",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^3.5.4",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.12.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.38.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.36",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "css-modal": "^1.5.0",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "match-sorter": "^6.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.11.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2-pre.0",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.4",
    "sort-by": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: `publicPath` should rather be `./`

Comment: If you see in code sample 01, the mode is still falling back to default (production) because when you `server` it takes `production` mode as default mode and serves your application (as there is no `mode` defined in your `config` file). Try explicit mention of mode `mode: 'development',` in your config file (and `devtool: 'eval',`  for development source maps).